# Google Analytics Android Unity - Application.LogCallback is obsolete

Tags: c#, android, google-analytics, analytics

Getting a console error in the googleanalyticsv4.cs file.

CS0618  'Application.RegisterLogCallback(Application.LogCallback)' is obsolete: 'Application.RegisterLogCallback is deprecated. Use Application.logMessageReceived instead.'

What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: RegisterLogCallback is obsolote and maybe won't be supported in future, so you should use the logMessageReceived method instead of RegisterLogCallback.

Comment: That simple eh, exactly as it says and it will function properly?